# Open JDK crashing eclipse

Tags: eclipse, java-7, java, azul-zulu

I'm working on migrating my project from Oracle JDK to open JDK - Zulu 7.

The problem is after I point my eclipse to the Open JDK version, the eclipse keeps crashing.
Once I point the eclipse to the oracle installation the eclipse is behaving properly.

Anyway I could solve this issue and continue to point to the Open JDK version?

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you see this when starting IDE itself with Zulu? The Eclipse launcher has a nasty hack that parses the libjvm library to determine the vendor and sets launcher parameters accordingly. If I recall correctly - it sets Xmx more for the Oracle java. So try to explicitly increase the Xmx value in your eclipse.ini (to -Xmx1024m at least or may be even -Xmx2048m) and keep using Zulu.

Comment: See https://support.azulsystems.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200572650-Eclipse-bug-can-cause-Eclipse-to-can-hang-while-using-Zulu-workaround-available for more details

Comment: Thanks a ton Sergey.. I just added this and it is working fine now, -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

Comment: Switch to Zulu 8 and forget about PermGenSize problems )

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing the heap size. Did you switch to Zulu 8 to get rid of this PermGenSize problems?

Answer (score 1):

-XX:MaxPermSize=512m

Try adding this in your eclipse ini file to remove this error.